# JDBC Driver not found error in Crystal Reports XI?

Tags: java, jdbc, crystal-reports, jndi, crystal-reports-xi

I installed crystal reports XI for the reports of my java application. When I tried to create a new mysql connection via the JDBC(JNDI) I got an error "Failed to open the connection. Details: JDBC Driver not found." So I followed the tutorials on the internet and edit CRConfig.xml to path my mysql driver. I placed it under the same directory where the other jar files were located but still I got the same error message. I also placed it on my environment variables but still no luck. Please help! I need this done by tomorrow.

edit: btw Im doing this in crystal reports. Im trying to create a report to preview on my application.

Comment: It should have worked after making the configuration settings that you have mentioned. Can you verify if the classpath element that you modified to add the location of the jar (in CRConfig.xml) points to right location where the jar is present.

Comment: yes i checked on it several times. but still same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something to check, if you have folder or filenames with spaces in them you should enclose them within quotation marks. If that's not the problem, copy your CRconfig classpath into your question, it might be some other issue.

Comment: I got it! Seems like crystal reports doesnt like other versions of it installed on the same computer. I removed crystal reports 8.5 which is also installed in my computer then it worked. :) Thanks for your help!.